# Halides of group 15 elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why are the pentahalides of group 15 elements more covalent than the trihalides?

Comment: This is a part of a much more general trend, neither confined to halides nor to group 15: the higher you go in oxidation state, the less ionic compounds you tend to get.

Comment: Yeah but there must be a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Fajans' Rule is  used to predict whether a chemical bond will be covalent or ionic.

Polarization will be increased by:

1) High charge and small size of the cation

2) Ionic potential

3) High charge and large size of the anion

4) The polarizability of an anion is related to the deformability of its                                            electron cloud (i.e. its "softness")

5) An incomplete valence shell electron configuration

In pentahalides, the oxidation state is +5 and in trihalides, the oxidation state is +3. Since the metal ion with a high charge has more polarizing power, pentahalides are more covalent than trihalides.